# Doctrine ORM\Table(name="name") not working

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, laminas

My Entity class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CustomerEntity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerRepository")
 */
class CustomerEntity
{
```

But when I am adding a customer it throws this error, it is looking for the wrong table.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'database.customerentity' doesn't exist

I did try with this, but doesn't help:

```
@ORM\Table(name="`customers`")
```

Schema generation shows this:

```
$ doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql

 The following SQL statements will be executed:

 CREATE TABLE CustomerEntity (id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
 .....
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have cleared the cache too

```
orm:clear-cache:metadata
orm:clear-cache:query
orm:clear-cache:result
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: I am in developer mode. And the `data/cache` folder is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is, that Doctrine expects each Annotation only once. Try this:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers", uniqueConstraints={
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerRepository")
 */
class CustomerEntity
{
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really frustrating, after going through ORM core codes, I was able to pinpoint the problem. Don't have time to investigate further to verify the bug or this being a feature (normal behaviour).

By inserting `@ORM\Table(name="customers")` below `uniqueConstraints`, ORM is able to recognize the table name.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CustomerEntity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerRepository")
 */
class CustomerEntity
{
```